# Running multiple user-heavy sites from a single codebase

Tags: load-balancing, server

I currently have a series of 15 sites, running off of **15 instances of the same codebase** and spread over four dedicated servers. Each site differs only slightly, with a different theme and some settings and translations changed to match the instance, but otherwise they are identical.

Here's an example of what I mean:

- **Server 1**

  - Site 1
  - Site 2
  - Site 3
  - Site 4
- **Server 2**

  - Site 5
  - Site 6
  - Site 7
  - Site 8
- **Server 3**

  - Site 9
  - Site 10
  - Site 11
  - Site 12
- **Server 4**

  - Site 13
  - Site 14
  - Site 15

When there was only one server, this was fairly easy to manage but now, with 15 (and growing) instances of different variations of the site, it's becoming a nightmare to manage and update.

I'm currently rewriting the codebase and would prefer to consolidate the sites into one, but I know that a single server with that much load will slow the system significantly.

I need a way that I can consolidate all this data without killing performance. I was thinking I could run the database servers on two of the servers, a cache (like varnish) on one, and nginx on one but this doesn't feel very scaleable.

Is there a better way I'm missing?

Comment: And there must be at least 15 different ways to implement a solution.

Comment: Also, alternatively, maybe there is a better way to deploy? I'm currently logging in to each server and running a custom made script to handle this, on each instance.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Maybe you could suggest a few of your most recommended? :)

Comment: You could try using hiring Paas or Iaas platforms, so they'll do your scaling and you'll only have to worry about your own code. (you should create and update script/enginge, so you wont have to, just use Git to update the clients)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## hosting

I would recommend using/hiring Paas (Platform as a service) or Iaas (infrastructure as a service). This way someone else will manage the hardware and the services and you will only have to worry about your code. The great thing is that the platform will scale your application to your need. (but bad code -> bad performance will cost you alot of money though)

Take a look at AWS for example: http://aws.amazon.com/

## updating

Also I would recommend using version control to update your sites.

personally i prefer GIT (because of the branches and local repository). you could make a branch for every client in which you do the custom layout code. when you deveop on your main branch you can merge it into all your other branches easily and just pull on your client sites.

Though i would suggest keeping your Custom code seperated from your basic code! (this should be easily split).

So just make a script that does `Git Pull` and you'll have automated your update-proces! (make it so that you can run this from an administrator back-end in your site, and your all set!)

hope this helps!

Word of advise: always work in a different branch then your production branch, and just release: `Merge` to the production branch when you have stable version.